# Dataframe conversion from pandas to polars -- difference in the final dimensions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-conversion, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm trying to convert a Pandas Dataframe to a Polar one.

I simply used the function `result_polars = pl.from_pandas(result)`. Conversion proceeds well, but when I check the shape of the two dataframe I get that the Polars one has half the size of the original Pandas Dataframe.

I believe that 4172903059 in length is almost the maximum dimension that the polars dataframe allows.

Does anyone have suggestions?

[Here a screenshot of the shape of the two dataframes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSJHl.png)

Here a Minimum working example

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4292903069,1), dtype=np.uint8))
df_polars = pl.from_pandas(df)
```

Using these dimensions the two dataframes have the same size. If instead I put the following:

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4392903069,1), dtype=np.uint8))
df_polars = pl.from_pandas(df)
```

The Polars dataframe has much smaller dimension (97935773).

Comment: Can you share some code and what else you have tried so far?

Comment: Try `polars-u64-idx` - see: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars#going-big

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default polars wheel retrieved with `pip install polars` "only" allows for 2^32 e.g. ~4.2 billion rows.

Do you need more than that install `pip install polars-u64-idx` and uninstall the previous installation.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the reason! pip install polars-u64-idx additionally requires Cargo and Rust.

Comment: On linux it should not. I think we only shipped that binary to linux atm indeed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Windows and after installing Rust  it gives as error "failed to get `ahash` as a dependency of package `py-polars v0.16.2". I'm unable to let it run.